# comparing string elements of a single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

have the following dataframe

```
      token name   ltp  change
0   12345.0  abc   6.0     NaN
1   12345.0  abc  10.0    67.0
2   12345.0  abc  17.0    70.0
3   12345.0  abc  17.0     0.0
4   12345.0  abc  18.0     6.0
5   12345.0  abc  20.0    11.0
6    6789.0  xyz   2.0   -90.0
7    6789.0  xyz   3.0    50.0
8    6789.0  xyz   9.0   200.0
9    6789.0  xyz  16.0    78.0
10   6789.0  xyz  16.0     0.0
11   6789.0  xyz  18.0    12.0
```

I need to achieve the following:

In column 'name', if there is a change in name the column 'change' should be 'nan'. if it is same, then change should be derived by comparing the successive ltp.

to identify each element of the column of 'name' I have used the loc method. Below is my code.

```
if df.loc[0:0,'name']==df.loc[1:1,'name']:
    df['change']=df['ltp'].pct_change().round(decimals=2)*100
else:
   df['change']='nan'
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

how can I achieve this compare?

Comment: `df.loc[0:0,'name']` is labeled with `0` while `df.loc[1:1, 'name']` is labeled with `1`. The can't compare.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to do `groupby` with `pct_change`:

```
df.groupby('name')['ltp'].pct_change()
```

Output:

```
0          NaN
1     0.666667
2     0.700000
3     0.000000
4     0.058824
5     0.111111
6          NaN
7     0.500000
8     2.000000
9     0.777778
10    0.000000
11    0.125000
Name: ltp, dtype: float64
```

Assigning it to a column in dataframe:

```
df['% change'] = df.groupby('name')['ltp'].pct_change().round(2).mul(100)
df
```

Output:

```
      token name   ltp  change  % change
0   12345.0  abc   6.0     NaN       NaN
1   12345.0  abc  10.0    67.0      67.0
2   12345.0  abc  17.0    70.0      70.0
3   12345.0  abc  17.0     0.0       0.0
4   12345.0  abc  18.0     6.0       6.0
5   12345.0  abc  20.0    11.0      11.0
6    6789.0  xyz   2.0   -90.0       NaN
7    6789.0  xyz   3.0    50.0      50.0
8    6789.0  xyz   9.0   200.0     200.0
9    6789.0  xyz  16.0    78.0      78.0
10   6789.0  xyz  16.0     0.0       0.0
11   6789.0  xyz  18.0    12.0      12.0
```